# How to pass the value in the particular index of an array in bash by the user

Tags: bash

I want pass a vaule in the particular index of an array one by one, how I can achieve this

My code

```
count=("$@")

read  -p  'enter index 0 '   {count[0]}
read  -p  'enter index 1 '   {count[1]}
read  -p  'enter index 2 '   {count[2]}

echo  "${count[0]}"
```

Not working

Comment: The sample code contains only comments. It will not do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reading variables (indexed, or not), it should not be placed into bracket. Consider

```
count=( "$@" )
read -p 'enter index 0' count[0]
read -p 'enter index 0' count[1]
read -p 'enter index 0' count[2]
...
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
for i in {0..2}
do
  read -p "enter index ${i}" count[0]

  echo  "${count[i]}"
done
```